# Will all nested columns be read in an ORC file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, orc

Say I have a Hive query like so:

```
CREATE TABLE student (key string, name string, course struct<class_name:string, class_teacher:string>) 
STORED AS ORC;
```

Because of the ORC file format, this will create 5 different columns:

```
| key | name | course | course.class_name | course.class_teacher |
```

When attempting to read only the `course.class_name` column, will both subcolumns of `course` be read anyway, every time? As in, both `course.class_name` and `course.class_teacher` ? As far as I am aware, ORC file format allows Hive to load only the columns needed for the query. So what will it actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is right. It will read the only column which is specified in the select query.
If select query is :

```
Select course.class_name from student
```

It will return only class_name.
In case if you want to query all the columns for the struct, you can use following.

```
select key, name, c.* from students 
   lateral view inline (array(course)) c
```